# Programatically inserted posts not showing in Posts Table

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post, wp-list-table

I'm trying to insert a custom post through a form. It's a brief post, most content are custom meta fields updated with `add_post_meta`. So far, post inserting is working fine, except for a detail. This is the post insert query I'm doing:

```
$venta = wp_insert_post(array(
  'post_name'      => "venta-$stamp",
  'post_title'     => "Venta $stamp",
  'post_type'      => 'venta',
  'comment_status' => 'closed',
  'ping_status'    => 'closed',
  // 'post_status'    => 'published'
));
```

Left as shown, it inserts posts as Draft without hassle. But if I uncomment `post_status`, the post gets inserted, but it doesn't show up in the *All Posts* Post Table related to that post type.

If I run a `WP_Query` for that `post_type`, it shows me the published posts and the post count —both in the Query and in the Post Table top tabs— reflects that those posts actually exist in the database, but can't see them in the Post Table. The only way to see a post in the WP Admin is editing the URL manually to get to the post, so I can modify or delete them.

What is actually happening? What can I do to test what is going on? Any docs I should look at, besides [the Developer Resources for `wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is quite simple: it's **`publish`**, not `published`.

According to [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters):

> **`post_status`** (*string / array*) - use post status. Retrieves posts by Post Status. Default value is '`publish`', but if the user is logged in, '`private`' is added.

Comment: did you solve it? for me, it is already "publish" but I can't see the post in the page. it is already in database.

Comment: It happened to me while working on this project that after saving so many posts as `published` **instead** of `publish`, they didn't show up in any proper query except the database. You could try to change the `post_status` of the affected posts as `publish` so they can show up.